# Call Project.Endpoint.static_url() within the config file

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, dry

I need to configure a OAuth protocol, and the logical place to do this is within `/config/dev.exs`, isn't it?

Right above, I configure the `Endpoint`. So in my app, I can write `Project.Endpoint.static_url()` and get eg. `http://localhost:4000`.

What would be the DRY way to get this value within the config?

```
config :project, Project.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  url: [scheme: "http", host: "localhost", port: 4000]

config :project, authentication: [
    client_id: System.get_env("CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret: System.get_env("CLIENT_SECRET"),
    site: "https://example.com",
    authorize_url: "/connexion/oauth2/authorize",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:4000/oauth/callback"
    # This version fails: Project.Endpoint.static_url/0 is undefined (module Project.Endpoint is not available)
    # redirect_uri: "#{Project.Endpoint.static_url()}/oauth/callback"
  ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should be aware that Elixir will resolve config files at compile time, which means that `System.get_env` will be evaluated when compiling your application. In the compiled code, the values will be fixed.

The Elixir team is working on simplifying this process, but for now the suggested way around this is to defer reading of environment variables until your application is started.

Generically, this can be done in your application module before starting children by calling `Application.put_env/3-4` and putting in values that were read from `System.get_env`.

Some libraries like Ecto also provide `init` callbacks that allow you to hook into the boot process to configure dynamically. See https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#module-urls

This would then also be the place to get rid of duplication. After all, configuration is then just Elixir code and you can simply set values based on other ones as you'd expect:

```
defmodule Project.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    Application.put_env :project, authentication: [
      redirect_uri: "#{Project.Endpoint.static_url()}/oauth/callback",
      ...
    ]

    children = [
      Project.Repo,
      ProjectWeb.Endpoint,
      ...
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Project.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

You can also do a mix and match of both config file and `Application.put_env` but then you need to take care of merging the values yourself.

Comment: Great answer! This is really taking me a step further into Elixir/Phoenix. :)